# export array to textarea including quotes and commas in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to export an array to a `<textarea>` element including quotes and commas, so then I can copy paste the text

How can I do it using javascript?

Comment: `textarea.value = JSON.stringify(myArray);`

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can stringify the array and set it as the textareas value

```
textarea.value = JSON.stringify(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using **join**

```
zArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

console.log(zArray.join("\n"));

textarea.value = zArray.join("\n");
```